# Creating javascript dynamically and use it for input type="text"

Tags: javascript

I've created a web app which can change elements by input type="text".App contains a dynamically created CSS and works fine.But dynamically created Javascript doesn't work.How is possible to enable dynamically created script in input type="text" and run change values while texting ? I want to type document.body.style.color='red'; or alert("Hello"); and see changes same second like with CSS.

```
var a = document.createElement("style");
a.type = "text/css";
document.body.appendChild(a);

var b = document.createElement("script");
b.type = "text/javascript";
document.body.appendChild(b);

function changeBackgrounds() {

  document.body.style.color = document.querySelector("#r").value;
  document.body.style.fontStyle = document.querySelector("#r").value;
  document.querySelector(".p").innerHTML = document.getElementById("r").value;
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = document.querySelector("#r").value;
  document.querySelector("video.video2").style.transition = document.querySelector("#r").value;
  document.querySelector("video.video3").style.animation = document.querySelector("#r").value;

  a.innerHTML = document.querySelector("#r").value;
  b.innerHTML = document.querySelector("#r").value;

  document.body.style.overflow = document.querySelector("#r").value;
  document.body.style.textDecoration = document.querySelector("#r").value;
  document.body.style.animation = document.querySelector("#r").value;

}
```

Comment: Create a JS Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**

> I want to type JavaScript into an input and have it execute immediately.

The following is a simple version of what your asking for, I think.

**Directions:**

Just type some JavaScript into the textarea and watch it execute. For example type: `textarea.style.borderColor = 'red';` (*don't copy & paste*, type out what you want). You can improve the statement detection if you want, as I said, this is a simple version.

**Answer:**

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

textarea.onkeydown = (e) => {
  // Statement detection
  if(e.keyCode === 186) {
    execute(textarea.value);
  }
}

function execute(text) {
  var script = new Function(text);
  return(script());
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: No friend.I saw this error right after the post and i've fixed the same moment.This document.appendChild(b) without body was because i've tryed something else with internal javascript and it didn't worked.Then i've created script and forgot to put body to post over here the problem.It wont work anyway.

How is possible to use javascript in javascript and change some value with input type='text' ?

Comment: I’ve made an edit, hopefully it’s what your asking for.